# Probability of drawing exactly two aces, at least two hearts and at most three kings when drawing $10$ cards from given $32$ card deck

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

In a deck of $32$ cards ({7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace} × {♣, ♠, ♥, ♦})

[image: deck of cards],

$10 $cards are drawn simultaneously. Give the probability of having exactly $2$ aces, at least $2$ hearts and at most $3$ kings.

It's a difficult question. There are a lot of cases to deal with.

**Addition 1  It's ok, i have an answer from my friend , this
probability is 23,2 %**

**Addition 2  I give the answer from my french friend  in original language (now translated)**

For a "hand" of $10$ cards having the required properties, we define the integers $x,y,z$ by:
$x:= \text{ number of kings present in the hand: }\: x\in \{0,1,2,3\}.$
$y: = \text{ number of kings of hearts present in the hand: }\: y \in \{0,1\}.$
$z:= \text{ number of aces of hearts present in the hand: } \: z\in \{0,1\}.$
$$\begin{array} {|c|c|}\hline  (x,y,z) &\text{nombre de mains de type }(x,y,z)\\ \hline  (0,0,0)& 3\times \left[ \binom {24}8 -\binom {18} 8 -6 \binom {18}7 \right]\\ \hline (0,0,1) & 3\times\left[ \binom{24}8 - \binom{18}8\right]\\ \hline (1,0,0) &9 \times\left[ \binom{24}7 - \binom{18}7 -6\binom{18}6\right] \\\hline (1,0,1)& 9 \times \left[\binom{24}7 - \binom{18} 7 \right]\\ \hline (1,1,0) & 3\times \left[ \binom {24}7 - \binom {18} 7 \right]\\\hline (1,1,1)& 3 \times \binom {24 }7 \\ \hline (2,0,0)& 9\times \left[ \binom {24}6 - \binom {18}6 -6\binom {18}5\right] \\ \hline(2,0,1)& 9 \times \left[ \binom{24}6 -\binom {18}6 \right] \\ \hline ( (2,1,0) & 9\times \left[ \binom{24}6 - \binom {18}6 \right] \\ \hline\hline  (2,1,1)& 9 \times \binom {24} 6 \\ \hline (3,0,0)& 3 \times \left[\binom{24}5 - \binom{18}5 - 6 \binom{18}4\right] \\ \hline (3,0,1)& 3 \times\left[ \binom{24}5 - \binom {18}5 \right] \\ \hline (3,1,0) & 9 \times \left[ \binom{24}5 - \binom{18}5 \right] \\ \hline (3,1,1) & 9 \times \binom {24}5 \\ \hline\end{array}$$
Let $A$ be the event whose probability is to be determined.
$\mathbb P(A) = \dfrac {\text{Card } A}{\text{Card }\Omega}, \:\text{Card }\Omega = \binom {32}{10},\:\text{Card }A =6\binom {24}8 +24 \binom {24}7 + 36 \binom {24}6 +24 \binom {24}5 -6 \binom {18}8 - 39 \binom {18}7 -81 \binom {18}6 - 69 \binom {18}5 -18 \binom {18}4.$
$$ \mathbb P(A) = \dfrac {14931234}{64542240} = 0.2314480.\dots .$$

### **NB we can simplify with a much simpler count:**
$$ \text{Card } A= a-b$$
where $a$ is the number of hands of $10$ cards with exactly $2$ aces and at least $2$ hearts and $b$ the number of these hands having the $4$ kings.
$a= 3\times \left [\Big(\binom {28}8 -\binom {21}8 -7\binom {21}7 \Big )+ \Big( \binom {28}8 - \binom{21}8 \Big) \right] \qquad b =6\binom {24}4 - 3\binom  {18}4, \qquad \text{Card } A= 6\binom{28}8 +3\binom{18}4 -6\binom {21}8 -21 \binom{21} 7 - 6 \binom {24}4 =14931234.$

**ADDITION 3  in the answer of leonbloy I rather find**

$$ P(A=2,H=0) = \frac{1}{\binom{32}{10}} \binom{3}{2}  \binom{21}{8}$$

$$ P(A=2,H=1) = \frac{1}{\binom{32}{10}} \binom{3}{2} \binom{7}{1} \binom{21}{7}+\frac{1}{\binom{32}{10}} \binom{1}{1} \binom{3}{1} \binom{21}{8}$$

$$ P(A=2,K=4) = \frac{1}{\binom{32}{10}} \binom{4}{2} \binom{4}{4} \binom{24}{4}$$

$$ P(A=2,H=0, K=4) = 0$$

$$ P(A=2,H=1, K=4) =\frac{1}{\binom{32}{10}} \binom{3}{2} \binom{4}{4} \binom{18}{4}$$

Comment: You haven't specified what the $32$ card are !

Comment: I have added an image

Comment: "Exactly 2 aces" has 6 cases, while "At most 3 kings has 15 cases (or you can just consider all of them and discard the "all 4 kings" case). Each of these cases result in some configuration of suits. Now check if you need to add any hearts to satisfy the remaining requirement.

Comment: For the last part about Hearts, the approach is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441823/abc-n-find-number-of-ways. The only case you'd exclude is the extraneous "9 hearts + 1 other" case, because your deck only has 8 hearts.

Comment: I have an answer from my friend. Should I delete this thread??

Comment: Hey, I'm writing an answer. Please check if it's correct.

Comment: Hey, ok of course

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer. But intuitively, because there are 6 ways out of 16 to satisfy the Aces condition, the answer has to be $\le 37.5\%$, so your answer is believable.

Comment: Personally, I think it's an interesting problem, so I hope you do not delete the question. (Your friend's answer is consistent with the results of a Monte Carlo simulation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

The probability will be

$$\frac{N}{\binom{32}{10}}, \tag1 $$

so the problem reduces to enumerating $N$.

It isn't clear to me whether the number of hearts drawn is (necessarily) independent of **either** the number of hearts drawn from the Aces, the number of Kings drawn, or the number of hearts drawn from the Kings.  Therefore, I will consider the following $16$ cases individually:

- Two Aces with or without a heart.
- $0,1,2,~$ or $3$ Kings, with or without a heart.

In each of the $16$ cases, I will deduct the enumeration where the remaining cards (non-Aces, non-Kings) did not bring the total number of hearts drawn up to $(2)$.

---

Let $a$ denote the number of hearts drawn from the Aces. 
So, $a \in \{0,1\}.$

Let $n$ denote the number of Kings drawn. 
So, $n \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$

Let $b$ denote the number of hearts drawn from the Kings. 
So, $b \in \{0,1\}.$

Let $f(a)$ denote the number of ways of drawing $a$ hearts from the Aces.

Let $g(n,b)$ denote the number of ways of drawing $n$ Kings, $b$ of which are hearts.

Let $h(a,n,b)$ denote the number of ways of drawing a **sufficient** number of hearts from the remaining $(24)$ cards.

Then,

$$\text{Let} ~N = \sum_{a=0}^1 f(a) \times \left\{ ~\left[ ~\sum_{n=0}^3 ~\left( ~\sum_{b=0}^1 g(n,b) \times h(a,n,b) ~\right) ~\right] ~\right\}. \tag2 $$

---

$f(a)$ equals:

- $\displaystyle \binom{3}{2} = 3 ~: ~a = 0.$
- $\displaystyle \binom{3}{1} = 3 ~: ~a = 1.$

Therefore, $f(a)$ is always equal to $(3)$.

---

$g(n,b)$ equals:

- $\displaystyle \binom{3}{n} ~: ~b = 0.$
- $0 ~: n = 0, b = 1.$
- $\displaystyle \binom{3}{n-1} ~: n > 0, b = 1.$

---

When $(n)$ cards are drawn from the Kings, 
then $[10 - (n+2)] = (8 - n)$ other cards must be drawn from the $(24)$ cards that are not Aces or Kings.

This can be done in $~\displaystyle \binom{24}{8-n}~$ ways.

In order to compute $h(a,n,b)$ you have to deduct the number of ways of drawing an insufficient number of hearts.

The number of ways of drawing an insufficient number of hearts is :

- $(0) ~: ~(a + b) = 2.$
- $\displaystyle \binom{18}{8-n} ~: ~(a + b) = 1.$
- $\displaystyle \binom{18}{8-n} + \left[\binom{18}{7-n} \times \binom{6}{1}\right] ~: ~(a + b) = 0.$

Therefore,

$h(a,n,b)$ equals:

- $\displaystyle \binom{24}{8-n} ~: ~(a + b) = 2.$
- $\displaystyle \binom{24}{8-n} - \binom{18}{8-n} ~: ~(a + b) = 1.$
- $\displaystyle \binom{24}{8-n} - 
  \left\{ ~\binom{18}{8-n} + \left[\binom{18}{7-n} \times \binom{6}{1}\right] ~\right\} ~: ~(a + b) = 0.$

---

At this point, the challenge is to apply the above formulas to the expression in (2) above, as elegantly as possible.

I will divide the enumerations into $(4)$ cases, depending on the possible values of $a$ and $b$.  For $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, I will let $N_k$ denote the enumeration for Case $k$.

Then $N = N_1 + N_2 + N_3 + N_4.$

**Some Shortcuts**:

- $~\displaystyle \binom{24}{5} = 42504.$
- $~\displaystyle \binom{24}{6} = \binom{24}{5} \times \frac{19}{6} = 134596.$
- $~\displaystyle \binom{24}{7} = \binom{24}{6} \times \frac{18}{7} = 346104.$
- $~\displaystyle \binom{24}{8} = \binom{24}{7} \times \frac{17}{8} = 735471.$
- $~\displaystyle \binom{18}{4} = 3060.$
- $~\displaystyle \binom{18}{5} = \binom{18}{4} \times \frac{14}{5} = 8568.$
- $~\displaystyle \binom{18}{6} = \binom{18}{5} \times \frac{13}{6} = 18564.$
- $~\displaystyle \binom{18}{7} = \binom{18}{6} \times \frac{12}{7} = 31824.$
- $~\displaystyle \binom{18}{8} = \binom{18}{7} \times \frac{11}{8} = 43758.$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~a=0, ~b=0}$.

$$N_1 = \sum_{n=0}^3 \left[ ~3 \times \binom{3}{n} \times h(0,n,0)\right]$$

where

$$h(0,n,0) = \binom{24}{8-n} - 
\left\{ ~\binom{18}{8-n} + \left[\binom{18}{7-n} \times \binom{6}{1}\right] ~\right\}.$$

$h(0,n,0)~$ equals :

- $500769 ~: ~n = 0.$
- $202896 ~: ~n = 1.$
- $64624 ~: ~n = 2.$
- $15576 ~: ~n = 3.$

Therefore,

$$N_1 = \left[3 \times 1 \times 500769\right] + 
\left[3 \times 3 \times 202896\right] $$

$$+ \left[3 \times 3 \times 64624\right] + 
\left[3 \times 1 \times 15576\right] = 3956715. \tag3 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~a=0, ~b=1}$.

$$N_2 = \sum_{n=1}^3 \left[ ~3 \times \binom{3}{n-1} \times h(0,n,1)\right]$$

where

$$h(0,n,1) = \binom{24}{8-n} - \binom{18}{8-n}.$$

$h(0,n,1)~$ equals :

- $314280 ~: ~n = 1.$
- $116032 ~: ~n = 2.$
- $33936 ~: ~n = 3.$

Therefore,

$$N_2 = \left[3 \times 1 \times 314280\right] + 
\left[3 \times 3 \times 116032\right] $$

$$+ \left[3 \times 3 \times 33936\right] = 2292552. \tag4 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 3:} ~a=1, ~b=0}$.

$$N_3 = \sum_{n=0}^3 \left[ ~3 \times \binom{3}{n} \times h(1,n,0)\right]$$

where

$$h(1,n,0) = \binom{24}{8-n} - \binom{18}{8-n}.$$

$h(1,n,0)~$ equals :

- $691713 ~: ~n = 0.$
- $314280 ~: ~n = 1.$
- $116032 ~: ~n = 2.$
- $33936 ~: ~n = 3.$

Therefore,

$$N_3 = \left[3 \times 1 \times 691713\right] + 
\left[3 \times 3 \times 314280\right] $$

$$+ \left[3 \times 3 \times 116032\right] 
+ \left[3 \times 1 \times 33936\right]= 6049755. \tag5 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 4:} ~a=1, ~b=1}$.

$$N_4 = \sum_{n=1}^3 \left[ ~3 \times \binom{3}{n-1} \times h(1,n,1)\right]$$

where

$$h(1,n,1) = \binom{24}{8-n}.$$

$h(1,n,1)~$ equals :

- $346104 ~: ~n = 1.$
- $134596 ~: ~n = 2.$
- $42504 ~: ~n = 3.$

Therefore,

$$N_2 = \left[3 \times 1 \times 346104\right] + 
\left[3 \times 3 \times 134596\right] $$

$$+ \left[3 \times 3 \times 42504\right] = 2632212. \tag6 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computations}}$

$$N = N_1 + N_2 + N_3 + N_4 $$

$$= 3956715 + 2292552 + 6049755 + 2632212 = 14931234.$$

$~\displaystyle \binom{32}{10} = 64512240.$

So, the probability equals
$~\displaystyle \frac{14931234}{64512240} \approx 0.2314.$

**Edit**
Just confirmed via sanity checking with Java program (assuming no programming error).

Pseudocode:
Used integer variables a thru j.
Let 1 thru 4 represent Aces, 5 thru 8 represent Kings. 
Let numbers congruent to 1 mod 4 represent hearts.

Forced a thru j to be in strictly ascending order: 
a : 1 thru 3. 
b : a+1 thru 4. 
This guarantees exactly two aces.

c : 5 thru 25. 
d : c+1 thru 26. 
e : d+1 thru 27. 
f : e+1 thru 28. 
g : f+1 thru 29. 
h : g+1 thru 30. 
i : h+1 thru 31. 
j : i+1 thru 32.

if f = 8 : skip, since this represents 4 kings.

add 1 to counter if at least 2 of the 10 variables are congruent to 1 mod 4. this represents that there are at least 2 hearts drawn.

Comment: The eonbloy method is very simple to understand, just it is desirable that he corrects calculation errors to achieve the same result as my friend. For the moment, I am leaning towards the user2661923 method, it is not easy to understand

Comment: @Jane Agreed that the leonbloy method is correctible.  However, I think that it is dangerous, in general to attack this type of problem as a *probability of events* problem.  Instead, the safer course is to attack the problem as an *enumeration of the numerator* problem.  This leaves less room for such errors as either overcounting, or incorrectly assuming that certain events are independent of each other.  I suspect that the correction to leonbloy's work will result in math that is a virtual clone of my math.  Also, it is dangerous to attack this type of problem without sanity checking.